# Can I use free provisioning to sign an iOS app in a CI pipeline?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning

I am currently developing my first XCode Swift app which I would like to try out/use on a couple of physical devices. This app is for personal use only and will not be used for distribution. I do not have an Apple Developer account so I am looking at "Free Provisioning". I am aware that this has the caveat that the app will no longer be useable after a weeks time.

Assuming I am happy to reinstall the app on a weekly basis, can I have a CI tool (such as Azure Devops or Github Actions) build me an `ipa` using XCodes free provisioning? If not, is it possible to build locally and upload somewhere so I don't have to plug every device into a Mac every time the provisioning expires?

I am new to iOS development and was hoping that I wouldn't have to pay the Apple Developer fee if I am not making use of the public app store (or any sort of public distribution method) as this is a private app.

Thanks